# stay focus & stay focused

Tags: phrase-choice

In some movie, someone said "**Stay focus!**" in English subtitle.
But I have never heard that phrase for my one year English learning period.

I only ever heard this : "**Stay focused** (on something)**!**"

Please tell me if "Stay focus" and "Stay focused" are both correct and all natural?

Hmm.. Which one do they commonly use more?

Comment: I don't agree with *focus*, it should be *focused*. Maybe, the translator was too busy doing other things that time!

Comment: I could contrive a scenario where “stay focus” would be appropriate, such as a film director shouting quick commands to a camera operator. In that case, you'd have “stay” as an imperative, appearing in its rare (archaic) transitive capacity with “focus” as its object. The camera operator would know to stay the focus, i.e. keep the focus where it is. It is much, much, much, much, much more likely that this is just a mistake. Noticing mistakes in subtitles is a good sign you are learning a language well.

Comment: What was the language of the movie?

Answer (score 1):

It is **stay focused**. Subtitles are often unreliable. The people who do subtitling are not well-paid. Trust your teacher.

The 'ed' in focused is pronouced /t/ a sound which is unvoiced and not strong so it may get lost. Sometimes sound recording doesn't capture everything that is said and our brain fills in the gaps. A native English speaker who hears **stay focus** will unconsciously fill in the gap and believe they have heard **stay focused**.